# after upgrade to 20.04 jpilot icon missing from aps

Tags: 20.04, jpilot

I upgraded from 18.06 to 20.04. looks good but jpilot icon is missing from sidebar. I checked in the files and it looks like all the data files are there just the icon is missing.
What should I do?

Comment: I entered commands and ok untill install, got error

Comment: Unsupported file ./libpisock9_0.12.5-dfsg-2build2_amd64.deb./jpilot-plugins_1.8.2-2_amd64.deb given on commandline

Comment: sudo apt install ./libpisock9_0.12.5-dfsg-2build2_amd64.deb./jpilot-plugins_1.8.2-2_amd64.deb ./jpilot_1.8.2-2_amd64.deb

Comment: ops - my error left out space in command. corrected and worked fine. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

The JPilot package is [not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=jpilot) for 20.04 LTS, but you still can download and install it manually from 18.04 LTS repository:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pilot-link/libpisock9_0.12.5-dfsg-2build2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jpilot/jpilot-plugins_1.8.2-2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jpilot/jpilot_1.8.2-2_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./libpisock9_0.12.5-dfsg-2build2_amd64.deb ./jpilot-plugins_1.8.2-2_amd64.deb ./jpilot_1.8.2-2_amd64.deb
```

and use it as before.

Comment: Thanks, worked very nicely.